# Intenal SATA Blu-Ray drive connected to laptop's USB 3.0 port via SATA to USB adaptor (with power supply) is not recognized

Tags: usb, 22.04, blu-ray

I bought an Internal Blu-Ray Optical Drive (5-1/2", 12x) equiped with a SATA interface (22 pins: 15 + 7); I also bought a SATA to USB 3.0 Adaptor with power supply. I connected the adaptor to the drive, then the power supply to the adaptor: the drive seems to be functioning because the door opens and closes at will. However, when I plug the adaptor's USB cable into my laptop's USB 3.0 port, the drive is not recognized by Ubuntu 22.04, neither in Nautilus nor in Disks nor in MakeMKV. What should I do? I don't even know where to start to diagnose this problem.

Thanks.

Following comments from matigo and David, lsusb doesn't give lots of information:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5650 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can hear the drive spinning the disk when I insert one. As far as what's the make and model of my drive, well, I bought it on eBay (supposedly new) and all I can give you is the drive's label:

[image: Optical Drive Lavel]

Looks like it's manufactured by Philips & Lite-On Digital Solutions.

Comment: Do you see anything listed in `lsusb`? If you have a CD or DVD of any kind and put it in, will the drive sound like it's spinning up to read the indexes? 

Comment: Does the maker of the drive support how you have connected it? Does the maker of the drive say it works with Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you enter the command `lsusb` while the DVD drive was connected to the computer? If so, the drive was not recognized and may not be compatible with Ubuntu.